# Reading Serial with Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, serial-port, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to get an Serial connection with a chrome app. I can connect to a device and send out data without a problem but cannot receive anything.

```
var onReceiveCallback = function(info) {
  if (info.connectionId == expectedConnectionId && info.data) {
    var str = convertArrayBufferToString(info.data);
    if (str.charAt(str.length-1) === '\n') {
      stringReceived += str.substring(0, str.length-1);
      onLineReceived(stringReceived);
      stringReceived = '';
    } else {
      stringReceived += str;
    }  
  }
  setStatus('Recieved');
};
chrome.serial.onReceive.addListener(onReceiveCallback);
```

I am using the chrome serial library and copied the example code from the website.

Comment: I'd suggest using a serial debugging tool to make sure the data is being sent like you expect to make sure its your code in the first place.  There is this one written as a Chrome App also which could be used to prove if the data could successfully be read from a Chrome App:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/serial-monitor/ohncdkkhephpakbbecnkclhjkmbjnmlo

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/serial/espruino/main.js for a complete implementation of `chrome.serial`.

You may also want to check for errors with `chrome.serial.onReceiveError.addListener(onReceiveErrorCallback);`